# What property initialization or callback method is needed for menu layout.operator_menu_enum()?

Tags: python

I am trying to have a Tools Panel menu item to set a Boolean Property in another registered class.   I am able to get the menu to appear:

[image]

But I get a crash with ACCESS_VIOLATION if I click on the item.

The fragment that creates the menu is:

```
#
#    Menu in tools region
#
class BONE_PT_BoneAnimToolsPanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_label = "Bone Animation Bulk Keys"
    bl_space_type = "VIEW_3D"
    bl_region_type = "UI"
    bl_category = "Tool"
    bl_context = "posemode"
    bl_options = {'HEADER_LAYOUT_EXPAND'}

        
    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        layout.emboss = 'PULLDOWN_MENU'
        r = layout.row()        
        r.label( text='select one of:' )
        r = layout.row()
        l=r.column()
        item = l.operator_menu_enum( 'pose.multi_key_inserts', 'only_change_idx', text='only_change_idx' )
```

and here is the class that is referenced in the menu item, with some properties defined.   I believe this is where I'm missing some definitions or callback methods to handle the event:

```
################################################################
class MY_MT_MultiKeyInserts(bpy.types.Operator):
    """add keys to any bones with changed transforms"""
    bl_idname = "pose.multi_key_inserts"
    bl_label = "Add keys to transformed bones"
    bl_description = "add keys to any bones with changed transforms"    
            
    initialized = bpy.props.BoolProperty( default = False )
    
    only_change_idx = bpy.props.BoolProperty(
        name="Only keyinsert changed dimensions in bone group", 
                        description='only key changed dimensions',
                        default = False)
```

I look for a wizard.  In terms of examples, the API docs are, well, you know.  And my searches here lead to sparse results.

Full script is in: [image]

Comment: in line 181 you wrote "MultiKeyInsertParams( self )" but isn't self there an operator and your class expects a menu? i might nothing have to do with your problem so...but i think that's a problem too.

Comment: @Chris -- thanks for the look-see and yes that might also be a "next up" problem to solve, or to clean up as I left in a possible pop-up menu and am leaning towards the Tool panel menu instead.  It certainly makes the code harder to follow at this point and should have commented this out.